# meaning of "as it were"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The great enemy of clear language is insincerity. When there is a gap between one's real and one's declared aims, **one turns as it were instinctively to long words and exhausted idioms,** like a cuttlefish spurting out ink - *Politics and the English Language by George Orwell*

I can understand the boldface part, but then what does "as it were" mean here? I would appreciate it if you could rephrase the bold part.  Thank you.

Comment: Several dictionaries explain this expression, for example, http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/as-it-were

Comment: Thank you. I should have done more research before putting out a question. I've got it now.